# how do I deploy play framework ( .zip) to Tomcat server

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, tomcat7

I am trying to build the play framework in Jenkins. I have a .zip artifact build by dist goal in jenkins.

How do I deploy that to .zip to tomcat?

Answer (score 0):

If really want to do that (I will strongly advise you to use built-in Netty, which is faster and have more features), you could do that with the help of [play2-war-plugin](https://github.com/play2war/play2-war-plugin), which will help you to generate **war** file, that you could easily deploy into Servlet containers like Tomcat, JBoss, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the response.. it helped.. now I am doing the deployment to EC2 directly and I get lot of exceptions like the below. Can you give me some hint on this.


@733ila33k: Cannot init the Global object
        at play.api.WithDefaultGlobal$$anonfun$play$api$WithDefaultGlobal$$globalInstance$1.apply(Application.scala:55)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: rb/common/Global : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:803)

Comment: no, that's not how it works, if it help you, you set +1 and confirm this answer, and then asks another question about your errors

Comment: Cool.. sorry was not knowing about it.. let me give a +
But I don't have enough points to give +1, its not even showing in the answer. Oh yes I remember- since I am new to stackoverflow I got a message that unless I earn 15+ my likes will not be shown.. Sorry for that.